# What is specifically a Command Line Argument?

Tags: c#, java, command-line-arguments

I always wanted to ask my college instructor what does it do specifically in `public static void main(String[] args)` but I never actually had a chance because it was last term, I never actually what does it do and what its importance, we just use because of practice. but as I try to learn C# these type of question arises, (I am trying to learn C# from the MSDN tutorials but the definition of command line argument is not that depth and dense) . what is a command line argument?

Comment: It arguments you provide on a command line.  Have you use a command line before, like a DOS Prompt?  Can you clarify what your doubt is?

Comment: there's a nice and clear wikipedia article on this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Arguments

Comment: why the downvote? I was asking because I need clarity.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey Yes I have used a command line, like DOS.my doubt is what is command line argument, now that I've seen it I am partially understanding it. will my program still work if I am using an IDE? if  I remove (String[] args)? or no?

Comment: I didn't down vote, but its hard to know what you need clarity on.  All the answers here are stating what anyone who has used a computer should really know already.

Comment: Ok, now we get down to the real question IMHO. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Anything that is passed after the main executable filename:

`helloworld.exe arg1 arg2 "arg 3"`

In this case, the console will interpret `arg1` and `arg2` as the first two arguments, and `"arg 3"` as the third.  CLIs (in this case Command Line Interpreters) will use space as a delimiter.

Remember also that if the path of the executable contains spaces:

`hello world.exe`

Then a command line interpreter typically interprets `hello` as the command, with `world.exe` as the first argument; thus in this case the quotes are important to actually delineate where the command ends and the arguments begin.

Your application has no control as to how the quotes are parsed; therefore if you need to have your own quoting system for arguments (e.g. if you are packing runtime parameters into a single commend-line argument) you will likely have to build your own parser and use your own quoting system; e.g. use `'` or even brackets.

Comment: how do I actually see the Command Line Arguments in java? how do I actually print them?

Comment: Sorry if this sounds harsh, but I am sure you could quite easily google that, or indeed find another QA on here with the answer you need.  If not, ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

A command line argument is an argument passed to the executable when invoked from the command line ("DOS prompt"), e.g.

```
C:\Users\dtb>MyProgram.exe These are command line arguments
```

Also, when you associate a file name extension (such as .foo) with your executable, the file name is passed as command line argument to the executable when you double-click the file.

Answer (score 1):

Command line arguments are the Strings that are called with the program.  Take for example: `ping computerA`.  `ComputerA` would be the command line argument for `ping`.

Answer (score 1):

> Will my program still work if I am using an IDE?

AFAIK, All IDEs support program with command line arguments.

> if I remove (String[] args)?

When you start, only a method called

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

or

```
public static void main(String... args)
```

is called because that is what is expected.

If you have a method

```
public static void runme(String... args) // won't be called.
public int main(String... args) // won't be called.
public static int main(String... args)  // won't be called.
public static void main()  // won't be called.
```

these are not the same method and you will get an error.

Comment: In C#, `void Main()`, `int Main()`, and `int Main(string[])` are acceptable.

Comment: @dtb Interesting. Does C# support varargs and if so, is that acceptable?

Comment: Yes and yes, e.g. `void Main(params string[] args)`. The `Main` method also doesn't need to be `public` in C#.

Answer (score 0):

These are parameters you can pass your application at startup. They are seperated with spaces.
See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you pass your application some arguments. Say I will run your program like this:

```
java -jar yourApplication.jar Pavel Janicek
```

then

```
args[0] = "Pavel"
args[1] = "Janicek"
```

you can print out these later on, or use as variables for your program

Answer (score 0):

Command line arguments are those you supply when you run your program. Like `java -jar myprogram arg1 arg2` or for example in java when you run `java myprogram arg1 arg2` instead of `java myprogram`.

So, the below code:

```
for (String arg : args) 
System.out.println(arg);
```

The output will be `arg1 arg2`

It means `first argument = arg1  and second argument = arg2`.